# Problem with spin connection term

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry

While working out Kaluza-Klein compactification, I am getting  the unwanted spin connection term $\omega_{c}^{ac}$ .I have tried to show that this  is zero.But I am not quite sure of it.
What I tried is
\begin{align}
de^{a}=&-\omega^{a}_{b}\wedge e^{b}\\\\
  &=-\omega^{a}_{b,\nu} e^{b}_{\mu} dx^{\nu}\wedge dx^{\mu}\\\\
  &=-\omega^{a}_{b,c} e^{b}_{[\mu}e^{c}_{\nu]} dx^{\nu}\wedge dx^{\mu}
\end{align}
as it is antisymmetric in $\mu$ and $\nu$. So it is also antisymmetric in $b$ and $c$. Thus one can conclude from here that $\omega^{a}_{c,c}=0$.Is this correct?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Hi Rohit, welcome to phys.SE.  Can you edit your question to make it more clear what you are asking?

Comment: I would have expected a spin connection - can you explain why it is unwanted?

Answer (score 0):

Be careful the indices in the equations
\begin{align}
de^{a}=&-\omega^{a}{}
_{b}\wedge e^{b}\\
  &=-\omega_c{}^{a}{}_{b}  \;\;e^{c}\wedge e^{b}\\
  &=-\omega_c{}^{a}{}_{b} e^{c}_{[\mu}e^{b}_{\nu]}\;\; dx^{\mu}\wedge dx^{\nu}
\end{align}
May be you are right.